# MS Excel, using field values as filterable keywords

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file with several filterable columns. One of these columns has a comma delimited list of people's initials. I was wondering if there was a way to treat each person's initials as a keyword such that when I filter the columns, I can see all line items with person1 and person2 even if they aren't listed together?
[Here is how it's formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Maa.png)

I would like to be able to select one person's initials from the 'Reference Person' column filter and have the results displayed contain all projects with that person. To my knowledge, how it works now is that each entry is a possible filter. Rather than having to sort through the filter options for all entries with the initials I want, I would like the filter options to be broken down into "keywords"

Comment: Can you provide us with example data, and output you want?

Comment: updated to show more detail

Comment: As I understand it, you want to filter for `KVL` and show all projects with `KVL`, so it behaves like tags, right?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Label / Tag Items in a Spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/405215/how-to-label-tag-items-in-a-spreadsheet)

Comment: You can't use filtered lists, but the link I provided already gives a solution as a VBA code for that.

Comment: Played a bit with filter, and it turns out you can **search** for a single tag. Using text filter, you can search for multi tag using `Contains` and `OR`

Comment: So it would seem. Looks like I should play with it a bit more before I ask a question next time. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: As what @Vylix said, "Dropdown Arrow -> Text Filter -> Contains" and enter the person you would like to look up. So doing this, if you did this and entered ARS, even with other people working on the project, it would show the ones ARS was apart of